# How to set dotted line length as less than 1 in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set a theme with a dotted gridline that has a length of less than 1, but I am not sure if that is possible given that the units are in hexadecimal. Right now I have the linetype set to "11", when I really want it to be something similar to c("0.5", "1").

Here is the ggplot2 material I am referencing in my attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)

#A simple plot with manually set dashes.
#The first numeral is units of dash length, the second units in the gap in hexadecimal. 
lty <- c("11", "18", "1f", "81", "88", "8f", "f1", "f8", "ff")
linetypes <- data.frame(y = seq_along(lty), lty = lty) 

ggplot(linetypes, aes(0, y)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = 5, yend = y, linetype = lty)) + 
  scale_linetype_identity() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = lty), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_reverse(NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

Referenced here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/ggplot2-specs.html

Comment: What do you mean by "when I really want it to be something similar to `c("0.5", "1")`"?

Comment: The meaning of the linetype = "11" means the following. The first one means that the dot ha a length of one and the second one means it has a gap of one. What I want is a length of 0.5 and a gap of one.

Comment: In other words, you want the segments of the dashes to be taller than they are wide? Is that right?

Comment: @JonSpring I primarily am looking to make the dot narrower than "1". Not as concerned with height versus width of the dot itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in way to make dashes that are taller than they are wide; the closest you can naturally get is 1:1 using the "11" type in your example.

Here's a hack, but it's not very adaptable, i.e. really only works easily for horizontal lines:

```
lty <- c("11", "18", "1f", "81", "88", "8f", "f1", "f8", "ff")
linetypes <- data.frame(y = seq_along(lty), lty = lty) 

ggplot(linetypes, aes(0, y)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = 5, yend = y, linetype = lty), size = 3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = 5, y = y+0.14, yend = y+0.14, linetype = lty), size = 3) + 
  scale_linetype_identity() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = lty), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_reverse(NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

I suspect there's a better way to do this using `ggforce::geom_link` but I haven't figured it out yet.